# Funny error using cherrypy wsgi server

Tags: django, wsgi, cherrypy

I am serving my django project using cherrypy's wsgi server. The server serves all static and media files from django project. The code is the following

```
#create basic django WSGI app
app = WSGIHandler()
path = {'/': app}

#create app that handles static files from static root and put it in path
path[static_url] = StaticFileWsgiApplication(static_root)

#create app that handles /media and put it in path
path[media_url] = StaticFileWsgiApplication(media_root)

#dispatch the applications
dispatcher = wsgiserver.WSGIPathInfoDispatcher(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Close window to exit'

    #create wsgi cherrypy server
    server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(
        ('0.0.0.0', 8000),
        dispatcher,
        server_name='cherrypy-django',
        numthreads=20
    )
    try:
        server.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.stop()
```

and the static file app

```
class StaticFileWsgiApplication(object):

    #init function to get the directory of collectstatic (STATIC_ROOT)
    def __init__(self, static_file_root):
        self.static_file_root = os.path.normpath(static_file_root)

    #Every wsgi app must be callable. It needs 2 arguments
    #eviron: wsgi environ path
    #start_response:Function creates the response


    def __call__(self, environ, start_respone):

        def done(status, headers, output):
            #usefull for debugging
            #returns the output(actual static file)
            #also it produces the response using the start_response()
            start_respone(status, headers.items())
            return output

        #get the path_info see PEP 333
        path_info = environ['PATH_INFO']

        #remove leading '/' from path (URI)
        if path_info[0]=='/':
            path_info = path_info[1:]

        #actual file path in filesystem
        file_path = os.path.normpath((os.path.join(self.static_file_root, path_info)))

        #prevent escaping out of paths bellow media root (e.g via '..')
        if not file_path.startswith(self.static_file_root):
            status = '401 UNAUTHORIZED'
            headers = {'Content_type':'text/plain'}
            output = ['Permission denied. Illegal  Path']
            return done(status, headers, output)

        #Only allow GET and HEAD requests not PUT, POST, DELETE
        if not (environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' or environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'HEAD'):
            status = '405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED'
            headers = {'Content_type':'text/plain'}
            output = SimpleResponse(['405:Method not allowed'])
            output.status_code = 405
            return done(status, headers, output)

        if not (os.path.exists(file_path)):
            status = "404 NOT FOUND"
            headers = {'Content_type':'text\plain'}
            output = SimpleResponse(['Page not found %s' %file_path])
            output.status_code = 404
            return done(status, headers, output)

        try:
            fp = open(file_path, 'rb')
        except IOError:
            status = '401 UNAUTHORIZED'
            headers = {'Content_type':'text/plain'}
            output = SimpleResponse(['Permission denied %s' %file_path])
            output.status_code = 401
            return done(status, headers, output)

        #This is a very simple implementation of conditional GET with
        #the Last-Modified header. It makes media files a bit speedier
        #because the files are only read off disk for the first request
        #(assuming the browser/client supports conditional GET).

        #mimetype needs to be ascii not uinicode, as django is all unicode, need to do conversion

        mtime = http_date(os.stat(file_path)[stat.ST_MTIME]).encode('ascii','ignore')
        if environ.get('HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE', None) == mtime:
            headers = {'Last-Modified':mtime}
            status = '304 NOT MODIFIED'
            output = SimpleResponse()
            output.status_code = 304
        else:
            status = '200 OK'
            mime_type = mimetypes.guess_type(file_path)[0]
           if mime_type:
                headers = {'Content_type':mime_type}
           output = BlockIteratorResponse(fp)

       return done(status, headers,output)
```

I get an error in **call** about not initialising headers before using it...probably because all headers are inside if's. The error is

```
UnboundLocalError:Local variable "headers" referenced before assignment
```

The funny thing is that i get this error only on Mozilla but web works fine, everything is served correctly, and after i sign in to my webpage it doesn't show the error anymore.

Should I initialize headers variable in beginning of call like

```
headers = {}
```

And why is it happening only in firefox?

Comment: Why not use CherryPy's built-in functionality to serve static content?

Comment: Meaning? I tried some things but didn't work...Maybe an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve static content using CherryPy, you should use built-in tools -- see [Serving Static Content](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/progguide/files/static.html). I guess you need to create a CherryPy app serving static content only and then combine it with your Django app with `WSGIPathInfoDispatcher(...)`.

BUT what you should really consider is using nginx + uWSGI -- see [Setting up Django and your web server with uWSGI and nginx](https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html).

Comment: The cherrypy server is exported as an exe, and runs django locally, so cherrypy came as an easy and fast solution for that. I can't understand why there is no error when using chrome.

Comment: Per the code, it must be `If-Modified-Since` header and MIME type missing that affect it. Browsers handle those cache headers differently, hence the difference. Not sure if missing MIME is ok, but initializing `headers` totally makes sense.